# solve diferential equation difficulties

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'm studying math and I've founded this equation: $\frac{dp}{dt}=0.5p-450$.
I write it so: $p'=0.5p-450$. Derivating the two sides: $p''=0.5p' \Rightarrow p''-0.5p=0$
General solution: $m^2-0.5m=0   \rightarrow  m_1=0, m_2=0.5 \Rightarrow y_m(x)=c_1e^{0.5t}+c_2te^{0.5t}$

$p'(0)=-450$, them $dy_m(0)=-450 $

In the book, the result is $p=900+c \cdot e^{0.5t}$. How they find it? Thanks!

Comment: You can try the method of variation of parameters: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters

Comment: but it's a homogeneous DE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrating factor!!

$$ \frac{dP}{dt} - 0.5P = -450 \\
(Integrating\;\;factor)\\
\Longrightarrow \mu(t) = e^{\int -0.5\ dt} = e^{-0.5t}\\
e^{-0.5t}\ [\frac{dP}{dt} - 0.5P] = e^{-0.5t}\ (-450)  \\  
\int (\frac{d}{dt} e^{-0.5t}P)\ dt = \int -450\ e^{-0.5t} \ dt\\
 e^{-0.5t}P = 900\ e^{-0.5t} + C\\
P = 900 + C\ e^{0.5t}          $$

Good luck! C:

Comment: Thanks! Your answer was very important to me. :-)

Comment: No problem! I'm glad it helped! C:

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$\frac{dp}{dt}=0.5p-450 => \frac{dp}{0.5p-450}=dt$$

Then integrate both sides.
Another hint:$$\frac{d(0.5p-450)}{0.5p-450}=\frac{dt}{2}$$